# not always getting the right image

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-file

I have a custom camera that has a public method for getting the thumbnail of that last image saved to a specific folder on the sdcard...

that method looks like this:

```
public void getGalleryThumb(){
             // TODO add Logic for gallery images..
            File sdDir = new File("/sdcard/LC/images");
            File[] sdDirFiles = sdDir.listFiles();
            if(sdDir.length()>0){
                File lastPhoto = sdDirFiles[0];
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(lastPhoto.getAbsolutePath());
                //SET MY IMAGE VIEW BITMAP TO LAST FILE IN sdDIRFiles
                photo.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                btn_gallery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "num images in gal:"+sdDirFiles.length +"last image name: "+sdDirFiles[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

i have noticed that if i delete a photo from that folder the method above does not always retrieve the right image..  I have used:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
                         Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/LC/images/")));
```

upon deleting and writing new files to that sdcard/folder  but it doesn't seem to do the trick plus it forces this annoying toast message about the sdcard being mounted..

any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you want the last image, you'll need to sort the files.  'listFiles' does not guarantee anything.

Answer (score 0):

I was writing this in a comment, but I'll put the detail here.  Multiple issues:

- listFiles doesn't not guarantee order.  You'll need to sort your files by last modified.
- You shouldn't access "/sdcard" directly.  Your second snippet of code has `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.  Use that.
- You get messages about the SDCARD?  Where are they coming from?  If you mount it to your local machine, you won't be able to access it from your app while its mounted.

Comment: The files are named with a time stamp.. so i thought a list would be sufficiant and it is until i delete an image.. i assume the message comes from sendbroadcast

Comment: You should still sort them as desired, as there is not guarantee of how the files will be returned.  The OS may be doing some weird shuffling.  Sorting them is really simple, though.  Look at Collections.sort.